# How to declare a TypeScript interface where properties names are values in an array

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm trying to create a `.d.ts` file for a library that has a settings object that allows the dev to supply another object containing functions that will get called to perform logging.

Something like this:

```
type LogFunction = (message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]) => void;

interface Logger {
  warn: LogFunction;
  log: LogFunction;
  // several more methods here
}

interface Settings {
  logger?: Logger;
}
```

This interface works so long as the function properties are named `warn`, `log`, etc.  However, this settings object also lets the developer pass in other names to use for the properties/functions.  For example, instead of using `warn` as the name of the property/function to call, I can tell it to call one named `anotherName` via code like the following.

```
const settings = {
  logger: {  anotherName: function() { .... } },
  logLevelMethods: [ "anotherName" ]
}
```

How do I write this type of declaration?

I know TS 2.9 implemented some level of support for using Symbols as property names, but I can't find a way of associating the values in the array for key names in the logging object.

Am I overlooking it?

Thanks!

If it helps, I'm trying to write a declaration for the `jquery-mockjax` jquery plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use generics and mapped types to achieve this. You can defined `Logger` as a mapped type that takes in a type that will be a union of it's keys:

```
type Logger<T extends  string | symbol| number >  = { [P in T]: LogFunction}
```

And you can forward the type from `Settings` to `Logger`

```
interface Settings<T extends string | symbol| number = "log" | "warn"| "error"> {
  logger?: Logger<T>;
  logLevelMethods: T[]
}
```

When declaring an instance you would normally need to specify the type parameter:

```
const simple: Settings<"log" | "warn"| "error"> = {
    logLevelMethods: [], // while this can contain the names, it does not have to unfortunately
    logger: {
        error: () => {},
        warn: () => {},
        log: () => {},
    }
}
```

A better solution is to create a function that helps us to create a settings object:

```
function createSettings<T extends string | symbol | number >(settings: Settings<T> ){
    return settings;
}
const otherSymbol = Symbol("Test");
const settings = createSettings({
    logLevelMethods : ["warn", "other", "new", 0, otherSymbol],
    logger: {
        0 : ()=>{},
        // 1 : ()=>{}, // This would be an error
        // log: ()=> {}, // Also an error not in the array 
        warn: ()=> {},
        other: () => {},
        new: ()=> {},
        [otherSymbol]: ()=> {}
    }
})
```

This also has the advantage of enforcing the constraint that the array and the members of logger agree (provided no explicit argument is passed to the function)

Note: I used `string | symbol| number` as that is the maximum allowable domain for keys in `2.9` you can remove any of the members in this union to not support that kind of key (for example remove `number` to disallow numeric keys)